# What does the option --template in "rails" command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
$rails --help
...
Options:
...
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]  # Path to an application template 
                             #(can be a filesystem path or URL).
```

What does this option mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/148-app-templates-in-rails-2-3